# Getting Image meta data from folder path for chrome extension

Tags: javascript, html, image, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have made a custom homepage extension for myself so its not run on a server I just loaded unpacked, so far I have a html file for the page and a java script file for loading a random image from a folder, each images name is (num).jpg where num increases by one for each so I don't have to use a file reader I just grab them with a random number for num, this works but each of my images has a description that I would like to load onto the screen.

I have tried to use exif but keep getting the csp error and I tried adding the hash thing into the manifest and into the meta in html but neither of these worked and the script would only give errors, so I downloaded exif.js and put in folder I then loaded this from html and this worked but it exif could not get description from the image. I've looked all over the internet and stack overflow but cannot find how to solve this, this is my first time with javascript as before my extension just used html. I normally use unity and c#.
My current js is:

```
document.getElementById("btn").addEventListener("click", myFunction);

function myFunction() {
    var imgElement = document.getElementById('img');
    var folderPath = 'Images/Photoes/' + '(' + (Math.floor(Math.random() * 552)).toString() + ').jpg';
    
    imgElement.src = folderPath;
    var text = document.getElementById('imgD');
    
    
}

window.onload = function () {document.getElementById("btn").click(); }
```

EDIT: I don't think Exif will work as I said before i've tried it but I don't think it can get the title / description of an image which is what I need.

Comment: How did you try to "use exif"? To read the binary data of the image you can use `fetch('/path/image.jpg')`

Comment: @wOxxOm I ment after I had the file I tried to use it to get meta data from the image, but it could not get the title / description.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem was I was not waiting for file to load. I don't use the fetch but it makes a delay. EDIT: clearing old data so next photo has its description, other wise it uses old meta data.
Final JavaScript:

```
//in another function not just on its own
setTimeout(imageLoaded, 10);

function imageLoaded() {
    //get image
    var imgElement = document.getElementById('img'); 
    console.log(imgElement);
    //discard old data
    delete imgElement.exifdata;

    EXIF.getData(imgElement, function(){
        var title = EXIF.getTag(this, "ImageDescription"); // 'ImageDescription' might contain the title
        console.log(title);
        var imgD = document.getElementById('imgD'); 
        imgD.innerText = title;
    });

  
    console.log("Done");
}
```